# What do the tools such as 'police cap' or 'thief cap' do?

Tags: another-case-solved

I don't understand what "all next tiles are donuts" means.
If all next tiles are donuts, and you collect six footprints or something, what happens? I'm having a really hard time because with all the other responses I've read, other players say these tools are their favorite but I don't understand exactly how it works.

Please explain in detail.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It means that all of the **new** tiles that are added to the screen after you collect the next group (footprints, in your example) will be donuts (or whichever item is appropriate to the tool you use).

> Police Cap - All next tiles are donuts.
>
> Thief Cap - All next tiles are lockpicks.
>
> Fedora Hat - All next tiles are questions.
>
> Runner Band - All next tiles are footprints.
>
> Deerstalker - All next tiles are magnifiers.

Here are some screenshots:

In this case, I need 3 photos, which are gotten by collecting strings of questions. To maximize the *Questions* on the board, I can use the Fedora Hat tool and then collect the large bunch of *Footprints* you see here:

[image: Before shot.]

Now, I've collected all of the *footprints* and all of the **new** tiles that have been added are *Questions*, though, note that I did also get a *Map* because I'd collected sufficient footprints to get one, so you'll still get those bonuses:

[image: After shot]

Now I can collect the *questions* and get a bunch of the photos.

This is great because it increases the number of that item on the screen, allowing you to collect more of them and finish levels more easily.

Comment: Note that if you connect enough items to turn into the upgraded type, e.g. Five footprints will become a map, it will include as many upgraded items as you unlocked - so what you'll actually get if you connect six footprints is five donuts and a map.